# Need Value Of Number To Be Modified

Tags: php, post

I need the value of $N to be 0.05 each, however it must always round up to the nearest 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44, 0.55, 0.66, 0.77, 0.88, or 1(0.99). That means if the value was two, it would be displayed as (0.11), if it was one it would also be (0.11), but if it was 8 it would be (0.44). I have absolutely no idea how this works, and looking it up myself didn't get me very far.

```
$N = count($_POST['val']);
```

.

```
if(empty($_POST['val'])){
    echo "Please select at least one check box!";
}else{
$N = floor(100*ceil(($_POST['val'][$i]*0.05)*9)/9)/100;
    echo("$N items(s) selected!: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
        echo($_POST['val'][$i] . " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

I got `$result = floor(100*ceil(($_POST['val'][$i]*0.05)*9)/9)/100;`

Stepping by 0.11 should be by (roughly) 1/9, not 1/11.

- multiply the post value by 0.05
- multiply by 9, round up (ceil), divide by 9 to get our actual value
- truncate the decimal by shifting the decimal point right two positions, cutting the remainder off, and shifting it back.

**Edit**: Thanks Greg Hewgill for the catch; replaced round with floor function. It seems that PHP doesn't have a truncate function, and casting seems messier than some more number shifting.

Comment: When `$N = 17` for example, your method results in 0.89, not 0.88.

Comment: Its fine if it rounds up by 0.01, however its still showing up as 0.

Comment: @JohnBilbo: My code has `$_POST['val'][$i]`, so it needs to be in your for loop.

Comment: @JohnBilbo: I just noticed that I conflated $N with the $result that you wanted to print. It's fixed now, put my code inside your for loop.

Comment: @GregHewgill: And I even spelled your name wrong! *Hangs head in shame*